# Android: how to get Islamic/Hijrah date for India

Tags: android, hijri

I want to get the Hijrah date based on India location, right now I can get the Hijrah date for Saudi Arabia using **ummul qura** calendar, but I want to get the hijrah date for India

here is the code I am using for now

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun getHijriDate() {
    bindAddSalahTime.islamicDateLl.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val hijriDate = HijrahDate.now()
    val todayHijriDateStr = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMMM-yyyy").format(hijriDate)
    val day = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM").format(hijriDate)
    bindAddSalahTime.islamicDateTv.text =
        StringBuilder(todayHijriDateStr).insert(todayHijriDateStr.length - 5, "($day)")
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As we know `HijrahDate` will return `Saudi Arabia` date, and `India` will run behind one day to Saudi Arabia (in islamic dates) so we can minus one day from the `Hijrah` date, following is the snippet of the code.

```
val hijriDate = HijrahDate.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
```